# I/flutter (21425): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i am trying to make search in my books application with api
back end handle it as a get method when typing the thing want to search after the end point
https://thebook.tech/api/page/search/
i tested it in postman by typing anything after the link and it worked perfectly
Cubit class

```
  
  SearchModel? searchModel;
  List<SearchModel> items = [];

  void getSearchData(dynamic text){
    emit(SearchLoadingState());
    DioHelper.getData(path: 'page/search/$text').then((value) {
      searchModel = SearchModel.fromJson(value.data);
      items =searchModel as List<SearchModel>;
      print(items.toString());
      print(items[1].name);
      emit(SearchSuccessState(searchModel!));
    }).catchError((error){
      print(error.toString());
      emit(SearchErrorState());
    });
```

Search Screen

```
state is SearchLoadingState
                    ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : SearchCubit.get(context).searchModel != null
                        ? searchController.text.isEmpty
                            ? Container()
                            : ListView.separated(
                                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                    searchItemBuilder(
                                        SearchCubit.get(context).items[index],
                                        searchCubit!,
                                        context),
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                    Container(),
                                itemCount:
                                    SearchCubit.get(context).items.length,
                              )
                        : Container(),
```

Comment: I am not sure what your error is. Can you please clarify

Comment: Yeah this is really hard to know what's going on. If I had to guess it's this print line `print(items[1].name);`, but without knowing where the error is occuring, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: cant load all code

Comment: can I have any social account to contact you

Comment: Welcome to Flutter and StackOverflow, kindly provide the entire log which is printed in your console. That way it will be easier to find out what went wrong and where.